# Error in retrieving collection from firebase react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Hi i am new to react native and having trouble in retrieving the list from firebase collection. but when i use the following code it returns an error: 
 **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**
Please help me with the solution as i know am i doing something wrong here to **this.state.items**

```
firebase.firestore().collection('myCollection').get().then(x => {
              x.docs.map(doc => {
                this.state.items.push(doc.data());
              });
              this.state.items.map(value => {
                console.log('my val',value);

              })
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate your state, you need to call `this.setState()` and set its new value. Something like :

`this.setState({...doc.data()});`

Now, this error often come from the fact that the higher parent node of your jsx (the 'html' returned by your component) have more than 1 child. something like :

```
const App = () => {

return (
  <div>a node</div>
  <div>another node</div>
}
```

if it's the case (happen because of a `map` sometimes), then just wrap your content with a div, like :

```
const App = () => {

return (
 <div>
  <div>a node</div>
  <div>another node</div>
 </div>
}
```